# Functions giving unexpected behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am writing a program to generate primes in JavaScript. The problem is that the behavior of the program is very strange, it seems that the functions do not execute in order which prevents it from executing properly. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Generate Some Primes!</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Let's Generate Some Primes!!!</h1>
 <form id="userInput">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <label>Lower Bound (inclusive):</label>
    <input type="number" id="lower">
   </li>
   <li>
    <label>Upper Bound (exclusive):</label>
    <input type="number" id="upper">
   </li>
   <li>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate!">
   </li>
  </ul>
 </form>
 <p id="messageBox"></p>
 <ul id="primes"></ul>
 <script>
 var primesList = document.getElementById("primes");
 var lower;
 var upper;
 var NOT_STARTED = "Generating ...";
 var DONE = "Done!";
 window.onload = function() {
  userInput.onsubmit = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   writeMessage(NOT_STARTED);
   if (checkInput()) {
    checkNumbers();
    writeMessage(DONE);
   }
  }
 }

 function checkInput() {
  initializeBounds();
  if (lower >= upper) {
   writeMessage("Lower bound must be less than upper bound.");
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }

 function initializeBounds() {
  lower = Math.round(document.getElementById("lower").value);
  upper = Math.round(document.getElementById("upper").value);
  primesList.innerHTML = "";
 }

 function checkNumbers() {
  for (var i = lower; i < upper; i++) {
   if (isPrime(i))
    writePrime(i);
  }
 }

 function writePrime(p) {
  primesList.innerHTML += "<li>" + p + "</li>";
 }

 function writeMessage(message) {
  var messageBox = document.getElementById("messageBox");
  messageBox.innerHTML = message;
 }

 function isPrime(p) {
  if (p < 2)
   return false;
  for (var b = p - 1; b > 1; b--)
   if (GCD(p, b) > 1)
    return false;
  return true;
 }

 function GCD(a, b) {
  if (b == 0)
   return a;
  else
   return GCD(b, a % b);
 }
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

These are my problems:

1. <s>When the lower bound is close to the upper bound, and they are both relatively large numbers, *no output is produced* (for example try inputting 900 as the lower bound and 1000 as the upper bound), even though I know for sure prime numbers exist there, and that my method for generating them works.</s>
2. The primes should be displayed on the screen *as they are generated*, and not at the end when they have all been created. If you input 0 as the lower bound and 10000 as the upper bound you will clearly see this issue (I suggest running the snippet full screen and watching the scrollbar size).
3. This is related to number 2. The `Generating ...` message is never shown, only `Done`.

**EDIT:** I made some changes to the code that solved the first issue.

Comment: Please edit your question, "screwy javascript behaviour" is not a question.

Comment: @Soviut is that better?

Comment: Woah, what is up with the downvotes? I went from +2 to -1 in an hour. Please explain yourselves

Comment: Don't worry about your rep, worry about creating clear questions. Well written questions will get more upvotes and better answers.

Comment: @Soviut yes, but I would like to know what is wrong with my question so I can fix it. I'm asking for anyone who perceived my question to be subpar to give their reasons why so that I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Promises to break the blocking behaviour of the for loop and give the browser/UI enough time to render the results.

```html
<body>
   <h1>Let's Generate Some Primes!!!</h1>
   <form id="userInput">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <label>Lower Bound (inclusive):</label>
            <input type="number" id="lower">
         </li>
         <li>
            <label>Upper Bound (exclusive):</label>
            <input type="number" id="upper">
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Generate!">
         </li>
      </ul>
   </form>
   <p id="messageBox"></p>
   <ul id="primes"></ul>
  
   <script>
   var primesList = document.getElementById("primes");
   var lower;
   var upper;
   var NOT_STARTED = "Generating ...";
   var DONE = "Done!";
   window.onload = function() {
      userInput.onsubmit = function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         writeMessage(NOT_STARTED);
         if (checkInput()) {
            checkNumbers()
               .then(function() {
                  writeMessage(DONE);
               })
         }
      }
   }

   function checkInput() {
      initializeBounds();
      if (lower >= upper) {
         writeMessage("Lower bound must be less than upper bound.");
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }

   function initializeBounds() {
      lower = Math.round(document.getElementById("lower").value);
      upper = Math.round(document.getElementById("upper").value);
      primesList.innerHTML = "";
   }

   function checkNumbers() {
      var promise = Promise.resolve();
      for (var i = lower; i < upper; i++) {
         (function(i) {
            promise = promise.then(function() {
               if (isPrime(i))
                  return writePrime(i);
            });
         })(i);
      }
      return promise;
   }

   function writePrime(p) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         primesList.innerHTML += "<li>" + p + "</li>";
         writeMessage("Generating ..." + Math.round(100 * p / (upper - lower)) + "%");
         setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
         }, 0);
      });
   }

   function writeMessage(message) {
      var messageBox = document.getElementById("messageBox");
      messageBox.innerHTML = message;
   }

   function isPrime(p) {
      if (p < 2)
         return false;
      for (var b = p - 1; b > 1; b--)
         if (GCD(p, b) > 1)
            return false;
      return true;
   }

   function GCD(a, b) {
      if (b == 0)
         return a;
      else
         return GCD(b, a % b);
   }
   </script>
</body>
```

External link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d5bp7hok/).

Comment: definitely looks promising. I will proceed to test

Answer (score 0):

**1**: Use `parseInt()` to correctly convert the input (string) to a number.

**2, 3**: The `for` loop blocks the window thread, so this is why you aren't seeing the step-by-step results; the DOM will be refreshed only when the code finishes. The message is actually being set, but you can't see it because the process is blocked.

I have edited on your snippet, using the `setTimeout()` function, which will wait some time before calls.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Generate Some Primes!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Let's Generate Some Primes!!!</h1>
        <form id="userInput">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>Lower Bound (inclusive):</label>
                    <input type="number" id="lower">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Upper Bound (exclusive):</label>
                    <input type="number" id="upper">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Generate!">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <p id="progress"></p>
        <ul id="primes"></ul>

        <script>
        var primesList = document.getElementById("primes");
        var lower;
        var upper;
        var NOT_STARTED = false;
        var DONE = true;
        window.onload = function() {
            userInput.onsubmit = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                /* 3: let's give some time for message */
                writeProgressMessage(NOT_STARTED);
                initializeBounds();

                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    checkNumbers(lower, upper);
                }, 1000); // waiting for 1s to start
            }
        }

        function initializeBounds() {
            /* correctly convert the input's for numbers, using parseInt */
            lower = parseInt(document.getElementById("lower").value, 10);
            upper = parseInt(document.getElementById("upper").value, 10);
            primesList.innerHTML = "";
        }

        function checkNumbers(current, upper) {
            if (isPrime(current))
                writePrime(current);

            /* not yet finished */
            if (current != upper) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    checkNumbers(current+1, upper);
                }, 100); // wait 100ms for the next check
            }
        }

        function writePrime(p) {
            primesList.innerHTML += "<li>" + p + "</li>";
        }

        function writeProgressMessage(done) {
            var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
            if (!done)
                progress.innerHTML = "Generating ...";
            else
                progress.innerHTML = "Done!";
        }

        function isPrime(p) {
            if (p < 2 || !Number.isInteger(p))
                return false;
            for (var b = p - 1; b > 1; b--)
                if (GCD(p, b) > 1)
                    return false;
            return true;
        }

        function GCD(a, b) {
            if (b == 0)
                return a;
            else
                return GCD(b, a % b);
        }
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Solved #1 and #3. For #2, I can't afford the 100ms timeout because I need to check as fast as possible.

Comment: I think you can use a Web Worker instead, or just set the timeout for 0.

Comment: Yes for Web Worker. If I were you I would edit my answer to talk about them